# Can't detect custom framework code

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote a Swift framework that contains all of my model objects and networking layer. For example, my framework contains a `Restaurant` type:

```
struct Restaurant {
  let name: String
}
```

When the simulator is selected, everything compiles and runs fine.

When the physical device is selected, I get compile time errors. All the code I'm referencing in my custom framework cannot be recognized. This only happens if I try to build / run on my physical device; Everything will compile and run with no problems if I switch back to the simulator.

I tried to clean out my derived data, clean my project, and build/run my project. So far, it hasn't been working. Any advice / suggestions appreciated.

Update: I am also using Cocoapods

Comment: How do you have things set up in Xcode? Mine begins with the app project called up, the framework project .xcodeproj file dragged into the app project, and everything building together. That way my framework edits build with the app, and the app running on the device (I test with two) installed and running.

Comment: I did not drag the framework project .xcodeproj file into the app project, but I don't understand why that would be the issue...

Comment: I don't know either, but the only other way to incorporate your framework is to add the .framework bundle to your app project. I'm just looking at differences. I think derived data pertains only to the simulator and you said that works fine, so I'm focusing on devices and how things get installed there. Did your app ever run correctly on any device?

Comment: I decided to refactor my networking layer and model types into a separate framework. The app was running fine on a device prior to using the framework.

Comment: So it runs fine nowadays on a simulator but not on a device? The only other thing I can think of to do is delete the app from the device before plugging it into the Xcode connection and try to rebuild. That's as close to a device "reset" (like a simulator) that I know. Wish I could be of more help.

Comment: Thanks, anything helps. Just deleted the app, no changes. I finding this very strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iOS Simulator and real devices runs on different architecture. You have to build a universal framework that uses both architectures. You can read about how to do it here http://arsenkin.com/ios-universal-framework.html